general quadratic equation with variable coefficients
Consider an equation of the form $a(x)x^2 + b(x)x + c(x) = 0, a(x) \neq 0$. The solutions can be found from the equations $x = \dfrac{-b(x) \pm \sqrt{b^2(x) - 4a(x)c(x)}}{2a(x)}$ which doesn't necessarily simplify things. I'm curious whether there are/there can be derived some nice results on this problem. Perhaps it could be brought to a form where it is easy to solve using numerical methods, or maybe by adding some assumptions on the coefficient functions one could bring it to a nicer form. For example, with the assumption that $a(x), b(x), c(x)$ are periodic and even (for simplicity) and their Fourier series are uniformly convergent the equation becomes $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\cos{\dfrac{2\pi n x}{T}}(a'_n x^2 + b'_n x + c'_n)}=0$ where $T$ is the LCM of the periods of $a(x),b(x),c(x)$ and $a'_n = a_n, b'_n = b_n, c'_n = c_n$ when $n>0$ and $a'_0 = a_0/2, b'_0 = b_0/2, c'_0 = c_0/2$. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem this is any more helpful. But the fact that now we have $a'_n x^2 + b'_n x + c'_n$ is nice, because its coefficients are numbers.
Anyways this was just an attempt. So I'm wondering, can a nice result be derived for some general class of coefficient functions, not necessarily the one I described?

You could use Newton's method to obtain a solution for $x$. Start with any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, then iterate $$x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)} = x_{k} - \frac{a(x_k)x_k^2+b(x_k)x_k+c(x_k)}{a'(x_k)x_k^2+2a(x_k)x_k+b'(x_k)x_k+b(x_k)+c'(x_k)}.$$ Depending on the starting value $x_0$, this will usually converge to a solution.
